# Building a WordPress search query that ignores punctuation?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, punctuation

I've set up a search query like this:

```
<?php
$s = get_search_query();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    's' => $s,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$query_search = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query_search->have_posts())
{
    while ($query_search->have_posts())
    {
        $query_search->the_post();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

It works great, except when I'm searching for a post that contains punctuation in the title. For example, if the title is "Mark's Book" using "mark's" and "marks" both return no results.

If I just search "mark" it will come up, but I want either of the above keywords to also retrieve the post.

Is there something simple I'm missing as far as making this compatible with punctuation?

Comment: try by replacing `'s'=> $s,` by this `'s'=> addslashes($s),`.

Answer (score 1):

default get_search_query() pass through data on esc_attr() to ensure that it is safe for placing in an html attribute. if you want to off esc_attr() then try this code,

```
$s = get_search_query( false );
```

may be it'll help you

Comment: Thank you. This gets me half-way there. In my original example with the post name "Mark's Book"... with this change, searching for "mark's" now works, but if I omit the apostrophe and search using "marks" I still get no results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in this way:

```
$s = get_query_var('s');
$s = addslashes($s); //<-- even if you remove this the query will work
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    's' => $s,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$query_search = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($query_search->posts);
```

*Please Note: I have assumed the query string is accessed by `s`.*
Code is tested and works.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Like the other answer, this does half of it for me. For the post name "Mark's Book", this code will now work with the search term "mark's", but if I search with no apostrophe, "marks", it still returns no results.